# A first order PDE with unsolvable characteristic equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the following PDE:

$(rs+z e^{-s}-1) \frac{\partial\zeta(z,s)}{\partial s} + \mu(z-1)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\zeta(z,s) =0$,

where $r>1,\mu>0$ are fixed parameters. I tried to solve this using the characteristic equations (with auxiliary variable $p$). The first characteristic equation is

$\frac{d z}{dp} = \mu (z-1)$,

which yields

$z(p) = 1 + C e^{p\mu}$.

The second characteristic equation is

$\frac{ds}{dp} = rs(p) + z(p)e^{-s(p)}-1$.

Filling in the formula for $z$ yields

$\frac{ds}{dp} = rs(p) + (1 + C e^{p\mu})e^{-s(p)}-1$.

However, as far as I can see, this differential equation cannot be solved(?).

Is there a way to get around this and get an analytic (approximate) solution to this PDE? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dz}{dt}=\mu(z-1)$ , letting $z(0)=2$ , we have $z=e^{\mu t}+1$

$\dfrac{ds}{dt}=rs+ze^{-s}-1=e^{\mu t-s}+e^{-s}+rs-1$

$(e^{\mu t-s}+e^{-s}+rs-1)\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$

Let $u=\mu t-s$ ,

Then $t=\dfrac{u+s}{\mu}$

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=\dfrac{1}{\mu}\dfrac{du}{ds}+\dfrac{1}{\mu}$

$\therefore(e^u+e^{-s}+rs-1)\left(\dfrac{1}{\mu}\dfrac{du}{ds}+\dfrac{1}{\mu}\right)=1$

$(e^u+e^{-s}+rs-1)\dfrac{du}{ds}+e^u+e^{-s}+rs-1=\mu$

Comment: According to Mathematica this ODE also does not have an analytical solution. So how exactly does this help? I don't see why this is a hint.